# Need to know what a parameter in YouTube url means

Tags: youtube, video

I have a link in my history which shows `&feature=emb_rel_end` at the end. I know that `emb_logo` is the parameter when you open a YouTube video by clicking on the logo in an embedded player. What does `emb_rel_end` mean? It's funny that I can't find the answer on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that on an **emb**edded video, you clicked on a **rel**ated video at the **end**. Y'know, the screen after the video is done and it tiles like 6 different videos to watch next.